# fileReader and scanner

Tags: java.util.scanner, filereader

I do not understand how to read data from `.txt` file below.

```
static final String DATA_PATH = "DataFile.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner fileReader = null;
    try {

        fileReader = new Scanner(new File(DATA_PATH));
        //Print out a trace of the program as it is running
        System.out.println("Debug: Scanner is open "+fileReader);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // If the file is not there, an exception will be thrown and the program flow
        // will directed here.  An error message is displayed and the program stops.
        System.out.println("The file "+DATA_PATH+" was not found!");
        System.out.println("The program terminates now.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Really? You even kept the Exercise Number

Comment: Where is your sense of adventure? :) look at the documentation for `Scanner` class (web || textbook), even typing variable with a period in the end like `fileReader.` should open IntelliSense and give you some ideas. (I'm not going to `-1` as you just starting stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of readFile by using the Scanner. So, you should import three important packages which are :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

After that, you create the file object along with the file's name parameter. Then, the scanner object is created. Finally, you can use while loop to read line by line or whatever you want.

```
 public class ScannerReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        // Create an instance of File for data.txt file.
        //
        File file = new File("data.txt");

        try {
            //
            // Create a new Scanner object which will read the data 
            // from the file passed in. To check if there are more 
            // line to read from it we check by calling the 
            // scanner.hasNextLine() method. We then read line one 
            // by one till all line is read.
            //
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

So, you can try to start from the code that I mentioned here and Practice more! from many tutorials on websites.